# Really SLOW update/upgrade and other problems - where to start to diagnose/solve?

Tags: upgrade, hardware, diagnostic

Last October I rebuilt my desktop and installed the AMD64 version of 13.10.

I have an MSI H87M-E33 Intel H87 motherboard, 
an Intel Core i3-4130 (Haswell) processor
4GB RAM
Crucial V4 64GB SSD

Most of the time it runs really fast (for me) but I have had multiple problems with it hanging (and needing hard resetting) and always when updating it's really really slow.

Now I'm upgrading to 14.04 and it's only 10% there after three hours! In the meantime I've downloaded Ubuntu onto a memory stick and installed on another machine and done lots of searching for answers...

I've done quite a lot of checking of my SSD and that seems to be working ok. Any suggestions about what the problem might be, or how to go about diagnosing it.

I've been using Ubuntu since Breezy and never had a problem like this before.

Comment: Ok, the upgrade has finished (I haven't restarted my computer yet because I don't know how the log files get erased and I don't want to lose info in them). It took over 7 hours!

Comment: One thing I can see is a lot of duplication in the /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-term log. For example the line `Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1)` is repeated 24 times, and `Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.12-1ubuntu2)` is repeated 5 times...

Comment: Most of the time seemed to be taken unpacking and preparing packages. All the installing and cleaning went very quickly and smoothly at the end.